# El problema se llama problema 3n+1

Tags: c

Tengo mi código, el cual, dado un entero positivo N , el problema 3n+1 consiste en determinar si es posible llegar a N=1 aplicando repetidamente las siguientes operaciones:

Si N es par, divídelo entre 2 .
Si N es impar, multiplícalo por 3 y súmale 1.

El problema con mi código es que no puedo determinar todos los valores, ejemplo numero a ingresar el 1, se supone que me debe de dar como numero de pasos 0 y el numero mas grande que toma 1, y mi código da como numero de pasos 0 y numero mas grande 0. Quiero saber si alguien podría proporcionarme alguna condición que me falte o algunos datos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n=0,max=n,j=0;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    while(n>1){
        if(n>max){max=n;}
        if((n%2)==0){
            n=n/2;
            j++;
        }else{
            j++;
        n=(n*3)+1;
        }
    }
printf("%i %i ",j,max);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: En tu código pones `n=0`, no `n=1`. ¿Lo has probado con el valor correcto?

Comment: Ya lo puse, si da me da el resultado, muchas gracias

Comment: Tu problema es que estás declarando a `n=0`, pero luego en el while dices que se ejecute lo de dentro cuando `n > 1`. Es decir, a partir de `n = 2`, por lo que o lo haces en un bucle for o modificas la condición del while.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n=0,max=n,j=0;
while(n>1){
```

inicialmente `n=0`, luego `max=n=0`. Es decir, inicialmente `max=0` **siempre**.

El problema entonces viene cuando vemos que no actualizas el valor `max` si `n<=0`:

```
while(n>1){
    if(n>max){max=n;}
```

Podrías inicializar `max` **después** de pedirle el valor inicial al usuario:

```
int n=0, j=0;
scanf("%i", &n);
int max = n;
```

La costumbre de declarar todas las variables al inicio del programa es antediluviana (creo que un estándar de los años 80 te obligaba a hacerlo así). Hoy en día no solo no es necesario sino que es contraproducente.

Declara las variables cuando las vayas a usar, no antes. Eso evita que tengas vivas variables que no necesitas para nada.